# Indeterminate two-dimensional limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm pretty sure that

\begin{equation}
\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^4y}{x^2 + y^2} = 0,
\end{equation}

but I'm having some trouble proving it.

The only technique I'm aware of that can be used to show indeterminate limits of $\geq 2$ variables exist is the Squeeze Theorem. I've tried applying it here (by assuming $|y| < 1$ and bounding the quantity of interest by $\pm\frac{x^4y}{x^2 + y^2}$), but I didn't get anywhere.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since $|xy|\leq \frac{x^2+y^2}{2}$ by the [GM-QM](https://www.geogebra.org/m/Fxu9tWwJ) inequality, you simply have:
$$\left|\frac{x^4 y}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq \frac{1}{2}|x|^3.$$

Answer (score 2):

Use polar coordinates: $x = r\cos t$, $y = r\sin t\Rightarrow x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, and $yx^4 = r^5\sin t(\cos t)^4$. So: $yx^4/(x^2 + y^2) = r^3\sin t(\cos t)^4 \to 0$ as $r\to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
0\le\left|\frac{x^4y}{x^2 + y^2}\right|=
\left|\frac{x^4y}{\|(x,y)\|^2}\right|\le
\frac{\|(x,y)\|^5}{\|(x,y)\|^2}=
\|(x,y)\|^3.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left|\frac{x^4y}{x^2+y^2}\right| \le \left|\frac{x^4y}{x^2}\right| = \left|x^2y\right| \to 0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The basic inequality here is $x^2\le x^2+y^2$, from which you get
$$
\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le 1
$$
with a similar one for $y$. So
$$
\left|\frac{x^4y}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le|x^3|.
$$